# Cast result of multiple tasks list to their POJO in Tasks.whenAllSuccess() (Firestore)

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

```
List<Task<DocumentSnapshot>> fetchUserTasks = new ArrayList<>();

List<Task<DocumentSnapshot>> fetchLikeTasks = new ArrayList<>();
```

So I have created two Tasks Lists. If it is one Task List I can cast `object` to `DocumentSnapshot` and store in POJO like this:

```
Task combineUserTasks =  Tasks.whenAllSuccess(fetchUserTasks).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Object>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(List<Object> objects) {

                        for (Object object : objects) {

                            UserModel userModel = ((DocumentSnapshot) object).toObject(UserModel.class);

                            userModelArrayList.add(userModel);

                        }

                });
```

But in case of two Task List how I can cast results for each List?

```
Tasks.whenAllSuccess(combineUserTasks, combineLikeTask).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Object>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(List<Object> objects) {

                        // How to fetch/cast data for individual POJO here?

                    }
                });
```

**Update 1:**

```
Tasks.whenAllSuccess(combineUserTasks, combineLikeTask).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Object>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(List<Object> objects) {

                        for (Object object : objects) {

                            UserModel userModel = ((DocumentSnapshot) object).toObject(UserModel.class);

                            LikeModel likeModel = ((DocumentSnapshot) object).toObject(LikeModel.class);

                            userModelArrayList.add(userModel);

                            likeModelArrayList.add(likeModel);

                        }

                    }
                });
```

Comment: The same loop doesn't work?

Comment: @DougStevenson are you suggesting something like this?

Comment: ```combineUserTasks```, ```combineLikeTask``` return different data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you have two types of lists, `userModelArrayList` which is of type UserModel, and `likeModelArrayList` which is of type LikeModel. To be able to add each object in its corresponding type of list, you should create the lists of Task objects to be of type UserModel and LikeModel. So please change the following lines of code:

```
List<Task<DocumentSnapshot>> fetchUserTasks = new ArrayList<>();
List<Task<DocumentSnapshot>> fetchLikeTasks = new ArrayList<>();
```

to

```
List<Task<UserModel>> fetchUserTasks = new ArrayList<>();
List<Task<LikeModel>> fetchLikeTasks = new ArrayList<>();
```

So instead of adding the `DocumentSnapshot` objects, add the actual objects. So use `toObject()` before. That being said, you can then check each object type using `instanceof` operator, like in the following lines of code:

```
Tasks.whenAllSuccess(combineUserTasks, combineLikeTask).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Object>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<Object> objects) {
        for (Object object : objects) {
            if (object instanceof UserModel) {
                userModelArrayList.add(userModel);
            } else if (object instanceof LikeModel) {
                likeModelArrayList.add(likeModel);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Now, you'll have each list populated with the corresponding object type.

Comment: Thanks @AlexMamo i will give it a try.

Comment: Give it a try and keep me posted.

Comment: Sorry i was working on reconsidering solution to my problem so couldn't respond on time. Yeah your solution definitely helped me. Regards